# How can I create a step definition file using rubymine?

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, watir-webdriver, rubymine

When I hit alt-enter on my steps text, only "convert scenario to outline" pops up, and not create step definition...do you know what i might be doing wrong?

[image]

also, my gem file includes cucumber and watir-webdriver.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hit on Google:

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/creating-step-definition.html

Looks like it is `Alt-Enter`, not hover.

Comment: yeah I've hit Alt-Enter ...and nothing. :\

Comment: I was just at that website too... @Beartech

Comment: Is there another way to create a step definition?

Comment: Are your steps behind highlighted? That's Rubymine's indicator that they don't exist yet.

Comment: the text in my steps are only highlighted if i do it manually with the cursor... @Beartech

Comment: I figured out my mistake... i put semi colons after "Given... etc." didn't need them >.<